# Cognos 10.2.2: Excel Report Redirects To Portlet When Opened from Portlet

Tags: cognos-10

The problem occurs when navigating to a report using A Portal Page:

When accessing a report which is set to open in Excel by default a user is not able to interact with the download notification in Internet Explorer 9.

-On clicking the link to run the report normal behaviour occurs (i.e. the prompt page is available)
-After selecting parameters and submitting the prompts the download notification message appears briefly. The user is then directed back to the portal page

It is possible to release this download through the ‘View Downloads’ menu option in the Internet Explorer settings menu.

When navigating to this report through the folder structure in Cognos Connection a user is able to run the report with the expected download notification behaviour (i.e. this is present at the bottom of the screen).

The problem is not present with IE 11 using compatibility view settings, Firefox or Chrome.

I’ve tried re-testing the issue with the Cognos urls added to Trusted Sites in Internet Explorer but the same issue occurs.

Has anyone encountered this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought I should update and say IBM have logged the issue and it will be fixed in subsequent release.